# How does WebAssembly.Global facilliate dynamic linking?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, dynamic-linking, emscripten

The following description is the introduction paragraph for [`WebAssembly.Global` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Global):

> A `WebAssembly.Global` object represents a global variable instance, accessible from both JavaScript and importable/exportable across one or more `WebAssembly.Module` instances. **This allows dynamic linking of multiple modules**.

I am trying to understand how `WebAssembly.Global` facilitates the dynamic linking of multiple modules. Initially, I thought this was related to multi-threading and that `WebAssembly.Global` allowed multiple Web Workers running the same `WebAssembly.Module` to coordinate somehow. However, I no longer think this is the case since it turns out that `WebAssembly.Global` is neither supported by [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) nor is [transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transferable_objects#supported_objects), which I believe means it cannot be sent with `postMessage`.

The [unstable ABI for dynamic linking](https://github.com/WebAssembly/tool-conventions/blob/main/DynamicLinking.md#interface-and-usage) mentions that `WebAssembly.Global` can be/is used in Emscripten for `env.__stack_pointer`, `env.__memory_base`, and `env.__table_base`, but I am still unsure why these imports have to be `WebAssembly.Global`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MVP of WebAssembly it was not possible to import/export a mutable (non-constant) global (WebAssembly.Global). This was changed by the [mutable-global proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/mutable-global/blob/master/proposals/mutable-global/Overview.md) (that is already merged into the current version of WebAssembly). The rationale is explained in details in the linked page. In short:

One could store the stack pointer into the linear memory (say at address #0) in a single-threaded setup, link several modules, and have a working program.

This cannot be done safely in a multi-threaded setup, because each thread has to have a separate stack pointer. One could simulate that in different ways (that have their costs; also noted in the previously linked page), as for example use different addresses for each thread. However, it is far better, if a [thread-local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) is available. There the globals come into play, as they act as a thread-local storage - each global has its own value for each thread.

One cannot "play around" that by using "just a second unshared memory instance for each thread", because the [multiple memories proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-memory/blob/main/proposals/multi-memory/Overview.md) is not (yet) [operational](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/).

Comment: Do you mean WebAssembly globals will act just like TLS variables in Wasm VM for different threads? And actually, the spec doesn't imply how the TLS mechanism is implemented for Wasm Global, right? It's just an implementation-dependent detail rather than part of the spec content.